# dj-stripe UpcomingInvoice usage

Tags: django, stripe-payments

Towards the end of a free trial period I am trying to send customers a notification that they will soon be charged with dj-stripe.  I am trying to use a webhook to initiate the notification and then UpcomingInvoice to retrieve the amount.

I can see in my stripe dashboard that I have customers with trial ending tomorrow and an upcoming invoice, however dj-stripe always returns an empty queryset.  In PDB when I try the code I also can't see any calls to the stripe api which would need to occur to pull the data.

```
@webhooks.handler("customer.subscription.trial_will_end")
def charge_upcoming(event, **kwargs):
    UpcomingInvoice(customer=event.customer).invoiceitems
    pdb.set_trace()

<QuerySetMock []>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by accessing UpcomingInvoice as a method on the Invoice model, so the above would be:

```
@webhooks.handler("customer.subscription.trial_will_end")
def charge_upcoming(event, **kwargs):
    Invoice.upcoming(customer=event.customer).invoiceitems
```